# Привилегии и разрешения. Windows

Tags: windows

В чем разница между привилегиями и разрешениями в OC Windows?

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит уточнить, в каком контексте вас интересует этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В контексте прав разрешение подразумевает согласие любого лица или группы лиц на совершение действия. Привилегия - это разрешение, предоставленное физическому лицу или группе лиц. Привилегии используются для различения разных предоставленных разрешений (включая отсутствие разрешений).

Привилегия - это разрешение на выполнение действия.

---

Разрешение - это свойство объекта, такого как файл. В нем говорится, каким агентам разрешено использовать объект, и что им разрешено делать (читать его, изменять его и т. Д.).

Привилегия - это свойство агента, такого как пользователь. Это позволяет агенту делать то, что обычно не разрешено. Например, есть привилегии, которые позволяют агенту получать доступ к объекту, к которому у него нет разрешения, и привилегии, которые позволяют агенту выполнять функции обслуживания, такие как перезагрузка компьютера.

[Ссылка](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41309/difference-between-privilege-and-permission) на первоисточник.